# How to change color on a Google Visualization table using only HTML in Wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress, google-visualization

I'm trying to figure out how to change color on all text in a google visualization table in wordpress using only HTML.

I've found multiple answers on stackoverflow, but nothing referring to using only HTML.

Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

The example is taken from https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table
Code is licensed under:https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Edit: cooldogyum's answer worked! I was pasting the stylecode on the wrong place in the "HTML code" block.

```
<style>
 #table_div {
  color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Here's what the final working code looks like. Thanks for your help, both of you!

```
  
 <html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

      function drawTable() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Name');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Salary');
        data.addColumn('boolean', 'Full Time Employee');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mike',  {v: 10000, f: '$10,000'}, true],
          ['Jim',   {v:8000,   f: '$8,000'},  false],
          ['Alice', {v: 12500, f: '$12,500'}, true],
          ['Bob',   {v: 7000,  f: '$7,000'},  true]
        ]);

        var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div'));

        table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }
    </script>

<style>
 #table_div {
  color: red;
 }
</style>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="table_div" style="“color:" red;”=""></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Styling happens in the JS options and are all loaded into one html element so you can style this container but not its contents using html.

Comment: Ah, I see. Was afraid that was the case, but I was too much of a noob to be sure. So simply put, it's impossible unless I also control the JS file.

Comment: Have you tried changing it with CSS?

Comment: Check out the docs (looks like you got this from here): https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/table and read cssClassNames you can assign CSS classes that you can then style.

Comment: Maybe theres a plugin for it. I think whats called "Additional CSS" in wordpress applies site wide. So its not a per page modification. I'll spend the night with this, so thanks for the direction.

Comment: Ok. Also try this, a better example for how cssclassnames gets used: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/examples. To do per page css with Additional you can use the id of the page.

Comment: Didn't know I could use the id of the page. That makes things easier!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML (Hypertext Markup Language) cannot be used (on its own) to modify the appearance of a page. HTML is purely used to define the meaning and structure of web content. I believe you’re meaning to reference CSS (Cascading Style Sheets) which is used to affect the appearance of web content. If you’re looking to change the color of text you can use the CSS color property.

```
<style>
 #table_div {
  color: red;
 }
</style>
```

Inline:
`<div id="table_div" style="color: red;"></div>`

Comment: I tried this solution before and unfortunally it didnt work in Wordpress. I think going about it this way is futile. Thanks for your efforts cooldogyum and Nathaniel Flick!

Comment: No wait it worked! I was just pasting the code in the wrong place.